# Getting the host name from a scoped service factory

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

One of the services I'm creating needs the current host name as a parameter (different requests use different host names, which affects external resources used by my service):

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(string host) {...}
}
```

I'm registering it as scoped:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped(s => new Foo(/* get host name for the current request */));
}
```

What is the cleanest way to get the host name at this point?

---

**Update:** I came up with this:

```cs
private static Foo GetFoo(IServiceProvider services)
{
    var contextAccessor = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var host = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
    return new Foo(host);
}
```

Is it a good/supported solution, or a hack?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're correctly defining it as scoped already, you can use the `IHttpContextAccessor` directly in your constructor of Foo:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public Foo(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor) 
    {
        var host = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Host.Value;
        // remainder of constructor logic here
    }
}
```

Something [similar](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/e447546e4ee57c9e13dfaf35c05c40b1d41ba41d/test/WebSites/ControllersFromServicesClassLibrary/QueryValueService.cs) is [done](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/3e9433639021255c1373c9a4bd36c4a511982d18/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/RoleManager.cs) many [places](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/3b32348cec62f51659a2e2e3302afefc5e36f49c/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity/SignInManager.cs) in the GitHub repositories; it looks like a perfect pattern to follow.

Comment: My *actual* code instantiates an external class which doesn't know about `IHttpContextAccessor`, but I get the idea and the examples are clear. Thanks!

Comment: I hadn't noticed this, thanks for including samples.

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon I want host name in my business layer to update base path for images which i am getting from DB so should i use IHttpContextAccessor in my Business layer or is there any alternative. i want to keep my business layer clean and don't want to use IHttpContextAccessor there.